# How to use a Loop to terminate a recursive function?

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I am trying to write a program that uses a loop for a recursive procedure instead of using conditionals, how do I prevent the calls running infinitely using a loop as the "break"?

I understand that the loop will automatically use the ecx as the counter and when ecx is 0, the loop will terminate, however, my program seems to run infinitely due to the recursive calls within the loop. I also tried with the jmp instruction and positioned the loop elsewhere multiple times and I still have the program running indefinitely.

```
.data
count DWORD ?     ;the counter for the # of times the loop ran
userVal DWORD ?    ;the # of times the loop will run according to the user

.code
    main PROC

        mov count, 0

    call ReadDec          ;read userinput for userVal, and stores it in ecx as counter
        mov userVal, eax
        mov ecx, userVal 
        mov eax,0

        call recur       ;call the recursion procedure
        ;call DumpRegs   ;for showing registers
        exit

    main ENDP 

    recur PROC USES ecx eax       ;the recursion Proc(objective: terminate the procedure with decrementing ecx 
                                  ; so the recursion will run ecx # of times) 

        mov eax, count                ;store  the count (starts with 0)
        call WriteInt                 ;prints the count in consol
        inc count     ;increment count everytime recursion is called    

        L2:     ;the loop

        call recur ; recursive call

        loop L2
    ret
    recur ENDP

END main
```

The expected output is `10 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` (`0` through `9` is printed because the recursive procedure should run 10 times, `10` is the userVal), However, I am getting   `10 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14...`(running infinitely)

Comment: ecx is never decremented (call then loop). Your code runs until stack overflow. Possibly decrease it before call or whatever Your intentions are.

Comment: I added `dec ecx` before the loop, still runs until overflow

Comment: @rAndom69: The `loop` instruction itself decrements `ecx`, it's equivalent to a `dec ecx/jnz` that doesn't modify FLAGS.  But `recur` doesn't save/restore ECX, so it destroys its parent's loop counter.

Comment: @PeterCordes, however, loop is never reached as there is just unconditional recursion. The ecx destroyed might (or might not) be true, as we don't see WriteInt. I.e. if you want it to end, you have to terminate cycle before recursion. If ecx is your recursion counter, then dec ecx, jz end of function.

Comment: @rAndom69: oh right!! yeah there's no base case for the recursion.  The function `jecxz`, or could jump into the loop past the `call`, so the loop condition is checked once before recursing (if they want to keep the nice `do{}while` structure.  Irvine32 functions like `WriteInt` use a beginner friendly calling convention that doesn't destroy any registers except the return value (and most functions don't have a return value), so ECX is safe from it.

Comment: Anyway, the obvious termination condition is to check that `count < userVal` before continuing, without using a down-counter at all.  And both those values can be kept in registers, because either way it's equivalent to an iterative implementation.  There's zero point to using recursion for this, and doing it that way won't teach you to save/restore any local state across a call because there doesn't need to be any.

Comment: Agree with @PeterCordes, Your goal of doing without conditionals is not going to be achieved by using `loop` which is a conditional. The task is too easy to do in assembly without recursion. My guess is that WriteInt is clobbering ecx and you'd have problems with a conventional iterative routine without allowing for that.

Comment: @cardiffspaceman: [What is the Irvine32 library and why do we use it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/54386649) explains that Irvine32's calling convention does *not* clobber any registers. 
 http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/writeint.htm shows it has not outputs, so it doesn't destroy any register values.

Answer (score 1):

> ... write a program that uses a `loop` for a recursive procedure instead of using conditionals ...

I find this an interesting challenge because it requires some out-of-the-box thinking. It has probably zero practical use but has nonetheless some proof-of-concept merits.

The `loop` instruction is encoded with a signed 8-bit displacement, which means that the conditional jump can jump backward **and forward**! In most (if not all) cases where `loop` is still used today we would only jump backward.
Putting the `loop` instruction on top, looks very unnatural but it works fine.

The below code works in 2 phases

- a preparatory phase pushes a bunch of return addresses on the stack (recursive calls)
- a productive phase pops all of those return addresses and prints the current number

Putting `inc count` before `call WriteInt` exposed `call WriteInt` as a [tail call](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjv_J-ij6biAhWGLlAKHQIhA8sQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTail_call&usg=AOvVaw0l8aQEowNXseO9o0Xlaltz) and so I could replace it with `jmp WriteInt`.
When the *productive phase* starts, `ECX` will be 0. Therefore instead of using a *count* variable in memory, I used the `ECX` register for this purpose.
The code is protected from entering an infinite loop and provoking stack overflow through the `jecxz Done` instruction.

```
    jmp     Start
; ----------------------
Recur:
    loop    .a          ; Jumps N-1 times
    jmp     .b          ; Jumps 1 time
.a: call    Recur
.b: mov     eax, ecx
    inc     ecx
    jmp     WriteInt    ; Returns N times
; ----------------------
Start:
    call    ReadDec     ; -> EAX (valid input is assumed)
    mov     ecx, eax    ; The unsigned number N is [0,4GB-1]
    jecxz   Done        ; In case N == 0
    call    Recur
Done:
```

Interestingly it is just as easy to write this using `loop` in the normal way, so jumping backward. It requires however an additional increment on the counter and it jumps around a lot more (See the comparison below).

```
    jmp     Start
; ----------------------
Recur:
    jmp     .b          ; Jumps N+1 times
.a: call    Recur
    mov     eax, ecx
    inc     ecx
    jmp     WriteInt    ; Returns N times
.b: loop    .a          ; Jumps N times
    ret                 ; Returns 1 time
; ----------------------
Start:
    call    ReadDec     ; -> EAX (valid input is assumed)
    mov     ecx, eax    ; The unsigned number N is [0,4GB-1]
    jecxz   Done        ; In case N == 0
    inc     ecx
    jz      Done        ; IN case N == 4GB-1 (stack overflow for sure!)
    call    Recur
Done:
```

Below is how I compared both methods. I removed the calls to *WriteInt* for obvious reasons ...

```
LOOP FORWARD                LOOP BACKWARD

    jmp     Start               jmp     Start
; ----------------------    ; ----------------------
Recur:                      Recur:
    loop    .a                  jmp     .b
    jmp     .b              .a: call    Recur
.a: call    Recur               mov     eax, ecx
.b: mov     eax, ecx            inc     ecx
    inc     ecx                 ret
    ret                     .b: loop    .a
                                ret
; ----------------------    ; ----------------------
Start:                      Start:
    mov     ecx, 25000          mov     ecx, 25000
    call    Recur               inc     ecx
                                call    Recur
```

The snippet on the left executed in 282 µsec, the snippet on the right did it in 314 µsec. That is 11% slower.

Comment: Your iterative version should probably not be called `Recur`.  Also worth mentioning that the "normal" way to use `loop` for a loop that might need to run 0 times is to put a `jecxz` before the loop, to maybe skip it.  Your backwards-jmp "normal loop" is artificially avoiding it and using `jmp` to the loop condition instead, but to make that work you're incrementing ECX in the caller to map 0..2^32-1 to 1..0, and for some reason also filtering out an input of 0 which I think you correctly handle after mapping it to 1.  Maybe you added that check before you put in the `inc ecx` in the caller?

Comment: That's funny that including an extra `jmp` in the normal path (not just the base case where `loop` falls through) is only 11% slower.  I guess `loop` is so slow on your CPU that it (along with `call`/`ret`) mostly hides the extra `jmp` cost!  I'm guessing it's an Intel, not an AMD; AMD since Bulldozer has fast `loop`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Your guess is right. It's an Intel Pentium dual-core processor T2080.

Comment: @PeterCordes Code corrected. I misread the docs for 'ReadDec' thinking input was limited to [0,2GB-1] and that (in the 2nd snippet) a counter wrap to 0 was not possible. Regarding the `jecxz` (in both snippets): in case the user input was 0, nothing has to be done (task description). That's why I filter out an input of 0 early on.

Comment: It just seemed weird for the recursive function to offload that to its caller when it could handle it on its own.  Makes sense to rule out that special case at some point for efficiency, though, before the actual part that can run many iterations.  (At least for cases where the extra handling is on the hot path.)